# Return Null in a query, instead of NaN

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, nan

in PostgreSQL, I would like a query to return Null, or empty value, instead of NaN (this NaN was inserted by python's pandas to fill an empty value).

Exemple:
Select name, age
From "People"

I would like to get:

John 24

Emily

Laura 50

Instead of:

John 24

Emily NaN

Laura 50

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you would like null-values instead of 'NaN' you could simply use:

```
SELECT name, NULLIF(age, 'NaN') From "People"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use :

```
SELECT name, coalesce(age, '') as age From "People"
```

Coalesce replaces a null value (first parameter) by the second parameter (here, an empty string).

If you need to test more complex cases than NULLs, you could also use CASE/WHEN :

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN age IS NULL THEN '' ELSE age END AS age from "People"
```

but COALESCE has better readibility for simple null handling.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think this doesn't answer my question. I want to replace NaN with Null. Btw, I think that adapting your second expression it can work. But Simo's answer is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `REPLACE`:

```
Select name, REPLACE(age, 'NaN')
From People
```

It will replace the value 'NaN' with an empty string if age field contains it.